# set time interval for laravel flash message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to display flash message for 3 seconds.
I have created flash message as session in controller.
I have received the message in view page.but didn't disappear after 3 seconds.
How to show flash message for 3 seconds.

```
controller 
 Session::flash('success', $id.' has been approved',array('timeout' => 3000), 'error');
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it's working out of the box. i can't find anything in the documentation. Normally you need some javascript and a timer to to remove the element after some seconds something like this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("div.successMessage").remove();
    }, 3000 ); 

});
```

or with jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#successMessage').fadeOut('fast');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will remove `success` message after 3 seconds from server session not from your browser/front-end. To remove it from front end use JavaScript `setTimeout` method

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#message_id").remove();
    }, 3000 );
});
```

`message_id` is the div id where you are displaying message.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your script and provide class to your flash message box. If you want to apply this on all than provide common class to your flash box

```
$(function() {
var timeout = 3000; // in miliseconds (3*1000)
$('.alert').delay(timeout).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An other option is to add to the header:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
```

then use it in blade as following

```
<div x-data="{show: true}" x-init="setTimeout(() => show = false, 5000)" x-show="show">
    <div class="alert alert-success">test2</div>
</div>
```